# OpenSSL 1.0.2.a and Centos5.7

Tags: apache-2.2, centos, openssl

I have an old version of Centos (5.7) and I would like to enable TLS 1.2 due to Google Chrome warning about TLS 1.0

I tried to update with yum but I can see that no OpenSSL 1.x could be installed upon this version of Centos. So I've downloaded it manually, and installed under /usr/local/openssl

Next step: how can I "link" it to apache (I've got apache itk)?

Just to be more precise, I need to improve my Apache web server TLS protocol from 1.0 to 1.2 and, to do that, I need to update OpenSSL and to let Apache use it (but I don't know how. Have I to recompile apache? If so, how?)

New OpenSSL version is 1.0.2a

Comment: Stop using CentOS 5?

Comment: @MichaelHamton yes, this could be a solution but, as today, isn't applicable at all. I need a solution based on current architecture

Comment: This isn't a solution for today, it's a solution for a year or two ago. You are _long_ overdue to upgrade this system.

Comment: @MichaelHampton: I perfectly know that and I also know that I can't migrate my system from 0 to 100. I need a working solution for this scenario while I test another server with a *slower* migration.

Comment: Not all of us have the luxury of an updated OS.